# Parsear html <iframe> guardado en una variable en JQUERY

Tags: html, jquery, parser

Tengo guardado en una variable lo siguiente:

```
register = "<iframe id='registro' src='estudios/info-estudios/'></iframe>"
```

Dentro de esa variable obtengo una tabla que existe en src='estudios/info-estudios/', que es la siguiente:

```
<table id="info-table" class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>

<tr class="active">
    <td>VALOR</td>
    <td>
        152
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="active">
    <td>REGISTRO</td>
    <td id='registro'>
        No
    </td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

Lo que quiero es parsear el campo de esa tabla con id='registro' con JQUERY y guardar el resultado en otra variable para poder utilizar.
Si imprimo register me muestra toda la tabla correctamente, lo que deseo es poder imprimir simplemente el valor SI o NO del campo registro.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como lo tienes ahora, lo que hay en la variable `register` es sólo una cadena con código html para un `iframe`, no tienes una tabla, es sólo texto. Me imagino que luego lo escribes en la página web y así es como ves la tabla.

Con jQuery puedes usar [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) para cargar el contenido de otra página en un elemento de tu página, pero lo que quieres es guardarlos en una variable. Para ello lo que puedes hacer es crear un elemento dinámicamente, cargar la página en él y después leer la variable.

Además, [`.load()` permite cargar sólo fragmentos concretos de la página especificando un id](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments), que será conveniente en este caso porque lo que quieres es el valor que hay dentro del `td` con id "registro".

Entonces podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
// crea un elemento `div` auxiliar donde cargarás la página
var pagina = $("<div>");

// usa `load` para cargar el id de la página especificada
pagina.load("estudios/info-estudios/ #registro", function(contenido){

   // guarda el texto del id en una variable
   var registro = pagina.text(); 
});
```

Y recuerda: `.load()` es una función asíncrona. No deberías usar el valor de `registro` fuera de la función de *callback* porque podría darse el caso de que aún no se haya cargado.